# Best practise in format for npm module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, functional-programming

I am creating a npm module that will take in some data from a js array of objects and allow the end user using the module to filter out only the relevant parts of data.

Im currently in the early stages of designing the api for the module and was wondering what is best practise these days between the below options

Example A:

```
const filteredData = dbOfObjects.filter1(arg).filter2(arg).filter3(arg)
```

or Example B:

```
const filteredData = dbOfObjects({
  filter1: arg,
  filter2: arg,
  filter3: arg
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The Example A will respect the order of your filters whereas the Example B will not as JSON keys are not ordered. So be careful with Example B if your filters are not all commutatives.